# Python: recursively copy batch of directories

Tags: python, recursion, copy

I'm trying to create a script at work that will allow us to enter a bunch of directory paths, and then recursively copy those directories to a new computer. This is for our computer renewal process with employees. I know I can use shutil to copy a source to a destination, but I'd like to take it a step further and collect all the source directories, then copy them over to the target hard drive using those same directory paths.

For example:
src = G:\users\%specificuser%\Documents
dst = C:\users\%specificuser%\Documents

I'd rather not have to type in source and destination every time. So I guess I first need to know if this is even possible in Python. If so, where do I start?

Comment: everything is possible in Python. :)

Comment: Do you care about file ownership and Access Control Lists? Metadata like that will not be copied with shutil.

Comment: the destination seems to have the same path as the source, apart from the disk it belongs to, so you can create the destination based on the source without re-typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
shutil.copytree(src, dst)
```

Or implement your own copytree, which traverses the directories creating them if needed (avoids the problem that "The destination directory must not already exist.", as pointed out in the comments), sort of a 1-way synchronization:

```
import os, os.path, shutil

src="G:\\TestCopy"
dst="D:\\TestCopy"

def copy_tree(srcpath, dstpath):
    print(srcpath)
    if not os.path.exists(dstpath):
        os.makedirs(dstpath)
    for candidate in os.listdir(srcpath):
        srccan = os.path.join(srcpath, candidate)
        dstcan = os.path.join(dstpath, candidate)
        if os.path.isdir(srccan):
            copy_tree(srccan, dstcan)
        else:
            shutil.copyfile(srccan, dstcan)

copy_tree(src, dst)
```

If you want to construct the user strings based on a specific user from parts of paths, `os.path.join` is good at doing that:

```
specificuser = "fred"
src = os.path.join("G:\\users", specificuser, "Documents")
dst = os.path.join("D:\\users", specificuser, "Documents")
print(src)
print(dst)
```

Output:

```
G:\users\fred\Documents
D:\users\fred\Documents
```

Comment: you should point out `The destination directory must not already exist.`, so repeating the process regularily from/to the same paths may require further intelligence

Comment: Yes, the OP might require something a little more subtle, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: upvoted, but hey, you went the full length. I imagined the problem would be when repeating the copy over the same path, i.e. when the destination exists already. In such case, I'd simply rename the existing one and keep using `shutil.copytree` :)

Comment: Thank you @Galax, that's exactly what I needed to get going on this. I didn't know about the os and os.path modules, so thank you for that. I'm super new to Python (in case you couldn't guess) so I'm just kind of jumping in head-first.

Comment: No problem, Python has a lot of useful modules that take the hard work out of this sort of thing. Good luck!